# How to copy HTML onto index.html in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my docker file I was wondering how can I copy the local html code which is in the same directory as my dockerfile. This command somehow did not work as when I ran a curl on my docker IP
it was not my html code it was the default  code.

```
FROM httpd
EXPOSE 80
COPY public-html.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you built the image, but did not run it.

Example to run it by mounting the file as a volume into the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web -v ./public-html.html:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Now you can do a `curl http://localhost:8080`.

Example for building it:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./public-html.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

More information [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-official-nginx-docker-image/)